# How can i change the speed of this clock

Tags: javascript, html

I have this clock that gets the local time. However i would like to change so that 6 hours in real time is equal to 24 hours in the clock. So to summarize the clock should speed up by 4x.

```js
            // This function gets the current time and injects it into the DOM
            function updateClock() {
                // Gets the current time
                var now = new Date();

                // Get the hours, minutes and seconds from the current time
                var hours = now.getHours();
                var minutes = now.getMinutes();
                var seconds = now.getSeconds();

                // Format hours, minutes and seconds
                if (hours < 10) {
                    hours = "0" + hours;
                }
                if (minutes < 10) {
                    minutes = "0" + minutes;
                }
                if (seconds < 10) {
                    seconds = "0" + seconds;
                }

                // Gets the element we want to inject the clock into
                var elem = document.getElementById('clock');

                // Sets the elements inner HTML value to our clock data
                elem.innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes;
            }
```

```html
<body onload="setInterval('updateClock()', 200);">
<h1 id="clock"></h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Should the time begin as the correct time when the page loads and go at 4x speed from there?

Comment: @arbuthnott no it should not begin are correct time, it should just keep going the fake time and stay faked time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a class I wrote for that kind of stuff.
For this demo I've included the seconds so you see the progress.

```js
/*
 a (pausable) linear equation over real time
 
  value = _speed * Date.now() + _offset;  //+ pausing logic
  
 so basically a clock, a stopwatch, a countdown, a gauge, ...

 since it is only a linear equation over time, it is independant of any interval.
 It computes the value (using Date.now()) whenever you ask for it. Wether this is ever frame or every hour.
*/
class Clock {
 constructor(value=Date.now(), speed=1){
  //state; changes only when YOU set one of the properties (value, paused or speed)
  this._offset = +value || 0;
  this._speed = +speed || 0;
  this._paused = true;
  
  //preparing a simple hook to get notified after the state has been updated (maybe to store the new state in the localStorage)
  this.onStateChange = undefined;
 }
 
 get value(){ 
  return this._paused? this._offset: this._speed*Date.now() + this._offset 
 }
 set value(arg){
  let value = +arg || 0;
  let offset = this._paused? value: value - this._speed * Date.now();
   
  if(this._offset !== offset){
   this._offset = offset;
   if(typeof this.onStateChange === "function") 
    this.onStateChange(this);
  }
 }
 
 get speed(){
  return this._speed
 }
 set speed(arg){
  let speed = +arg || 0;
  if(this._speed !== speed){
   if(!this._paused)
    this._offset += Date.now() * (this._speed - speed);
   this._speed = speed;
   if(typeof this.onStateChange === "function")
    this.onStateChange(this);
  }
 }
 
 get paused(){
  return this._paused
 }
 set paused(arg){
  let pause = !!arg;
  if(this._paused !== pause){
    this._offset += (pause? 1: -1) * this._speed * Date.now();
   this._paused = pause;
   if(typeof this.onStateChange === "function")
     this.onStateChange(this);
  }
 }

 time(){
  let value = this.value,v = Math.abs(value);
  return {
   value,
   //sign: value < 0? "-": "",
   seconds: Math.floor(v/1e3)%60,
   minutes: Math.floor(v/6e4)%60,
   hours: Math.floor(v/36e5)%24,
   days: Math.floor(v/864e5)
  }
 }
 
 valueOf(){
  return this.value;
 } 
 
 start(){
  this.paused = false;
  return this;  
 }
 stop(){
  this.paused = true;
  return this;
 }
}

function lz(v){ //leading zero
  return String(v).padStart(2, 0);
}

function update(){
  let {hours, minutes, seconds} = clock.time();
  let node = document.getElementById('clock');
  
  node.textContent = [hours, minutes, seconds].map(lz).join(":");
  
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
  //setTimeout(update, 250);
}

let clock = new Clock(Date.now(), 4).start();
update();
```

```html
<h1 id="clock"></h1>
```

> Thank you this is very good, the problem is that this clock should keep going and not start from local time each load.. How would i add that function?

For stuff like that I've added the `onStateChange` hook.
You can use it to store the state of this clock, when it is changed.

```
let clock = new Clock(Date.now(), 4).start();
//add the hook
clock.onStateChange = function(){
  //will be called whenever you change the state of this clock. things like changing the speed or paused state, or when you set the value.
  localStorage.setItem("clock", JSON.stringify(this));
}
//check wether there is a stored state for this "clock"
if(localStorage.hasItem("clock")){
  //simply overwrite the state of the clock.
  Object.assign(clock, JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("clock")))
}else{
  //if there's no current state stored, force storing the current state
  clock.onStateChange();
}
```

I've added this code seperately because I don't have access to `localStorage` in these snippets here on SO.

Comment: Thank you this is very good, the problem is that this clock should keep going and not start from local time each load.. How would i add that function?

Comment: @Thea added an example on how to store the **state** of the clock in localStorage, when it changes.

Comment: Oh nice, thank you. im very new to this with localStorage. Should i place this in a new script tag and what do i have to change/add to make it work properly?

Answer (score 1):

It's popular question in every language :). I'm sure you can find it on google, but... Here's sample:

```
let mydate = new Date();
let mydate_millisec=mydate.getTime();

let offset = 4;

function clock() {
  next();
  setInterval("next()", 1000 / offset);
}
function next() {
  console.log(new Date(mydate_millisec).toString());

  mydate_millisec += 1000;
}
clock();
```

Comment: The interval of `setInterval` and `setTimeout` are not reliable. They are more of a reccomendation: "call that function as soon as you get to it, but in at least xyz ms." and incrementing with that interval makes the progress even less reliable. It may be good enough for this clock, but generally it ain't a good approach.