# How to synchronize a countdown between a Swing-GUI and a WebApplication like Vaadin or native JS

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, vaadin

Iam trying to synchronize a Countdown from a Java Application to a Browser. The Countdown can be stopped, started and resetted anytime.

I have tried to implement this in Vaadin 13 but cant access the the UI Access Mehtod to lock the vaadin session. Now Iam trying to implement this with native JS and Ajax requests but iam not sure how to synchronize the stop/start and reset events without making an ajax request every second.

This is the Swing Implementation of the counter

```java
public void timer() {

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (seconds == 0  && minutes > 0) {
                    minutes--;
                    seconds = 59;   
                } else {
                    seconds--;
                }
                label.setText(minutes+":"+seconds);
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();

    }
```

Now I would offer a Spring Boot Rest API for the JS Code to ask for minutes and seconds remaining.

```
setInterval(test, 1000);

async function test() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://10.0.1.17/countdown", false);
    xhttp.send();
    //console.log(JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText));

    //Do Something with it

}
```

This seems to be an unreliable and unefficient way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this class out, from [another answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47511085/6567275)

```
/*
    a (pausable) linear equation over real time

        value = _speed * Date.now() + _offset;

        //when paused, it's simply: 
        value = _offset;

    so basically a clock, a stopwatch, a countdown, a gauge, ...

    since it is only a linear equation over time, it is independant of any interval.
    It computes the value (using Date.now()) whenever you ask for it. Wether this is ever frame or every hour.
*/
class Clock {
    constructor(value=Date.now(), speed=1){
        //state; changes only when YOU set one of the properties (value, paused or speed)
        this._offset = +value || 0;
        this._speed = +speed || 0;
        this._paused = true;

        //preparing a simple hook to get notified after the state has been updated (maybe to store the new state in the localStorage)
        this.onStateChange = undefined;
    }

    get value(){ 
        return this._paused? this._offset: this._speed*Date.now() + this._offset 
    }
    set value(arg){
        let value = +arg || 0;
        let offset = this._paused? value: value - this._speed * Date.now();

        if(this._offset !== offset){
            this._offset = offset;
            if(typeof this.onStateChange === "function") 
                this.onStateChange(this);
        }
    }

    get speed(){
        return this._speed
    }
    set speed(arg){
        let speed = +arg || 0;
        if(this._speed !== speed){
            if(!this._paused)
                this._offset += Date.now() * (this._speed - speed);
            this._speed = speed;
            if(typeof this.onStateChange === "function")
                this.onStateChange(this);
        }
    }

    get paused(){
        return this._paused
    }
    set paused(arg){
        let pause = !!arg;
        if(this._paused !== pause){
          this._offset += (pause? 1: -1) * this._speed * Date.now();
            this._paused = pause;
            if(typeof this.onStateChange === "function")
              this.onStateChange(this);
        }
    }

    time(){
        let value = this.value,v = Math.abs(value);
        return {
            value,
            //sign: value < 0? "-": "",
            seconds: Math.floor(v/1e3)%60,
            minutes: Math.floor(v/6e4)%60,
            hours: Math.floor(v/36e5)%24,
            days: Math.floor(v/864e5)
        }
    }

    valueOf(){
        return this.value;
    }   

    start(){
        this.paused = false;
        return this;        
    }
    stop(){
        this.paused = true;
        return this;
    }
}
```

I show this because if you take a closer look at it you'll see that the entire state of this thing consists of *two numbers and a boolean* and they only change when you do something, like start/stop it.

The actual value is computed from this state and the Computers internal clock.

So, if you synchronize this state between frontend and backend, they both run (mostly) in sync.

Why mostly? Because of the little delay before the other end has recieved the new state. For these few ms the two are out of sync. As soon as the other end has updated its state, they're again in sync.